# What is 'Direct' about Direct Examination? Why was it chosen?

Tags: legal-terms

Source: [*Ontario Small Claims Court - A Practical Guide*](https://store.lexisnexis.ca/en/categories/shop-by-jurisdiction/ontario-10/ontario-small-claims-court-a-practical-guide-skusku-cad-00935/details) (2011), p. 12.

> (i) Direct Examination of the Plaintiff
>
> **§1.31** Following the opening statements, the parties will then embark on the
> *evidential stage*. The plaintiff (the one with the complaint) is first to present
> his case. The self-represented plaintiff will testify in support of his pleaded
> case. If he has relevant documents (which can include photographs, emails,
> videotapes and sound recordings), then he will introduce them one by one as
> they are marked as exhibits. If the plaintiff is represented (for instance, by a
> lawyer or a paralegal), the representative will question him in the context of
> the issues. That examination is called "direct examination" or "examination
> in chief'.

Abbreviate Direct Examination to DE. What motivated the choice of 'Direct'?

My guess: In a DE, the witness should be on the questioning lawyer's side, and so should be answering the lawyer's question helpfully or cooperatively? But how's this direct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [my answer to your other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/24007/333).

Direct examination is so called because the witness was called by the party examining the witness.  Since there is nothing (figuratively) to cross, the examination may proceed directly.