# What is 'Cross' about Cross-Examination? Why was it chosen?

Tags: legal-terms

Source: [*Ontario Small Claims Court - A Practical Guide*](https://store.lexisnexis.ca/en/categories/shop-by-jurisdiction/ontario-10/ontario-small-claims-court-a-practical-guide-skusku-cad-00935/details) (2011), p. 12.

> (ii) Cross-examination of the Plaintiff
>
> **§1.32** Following the direct examination of the plaintiff, the defendant or his
> representative may then embark upon an examination of the plaintiff with
> two principal objectives in mind: either the destruction of the plaintiff's case
> through plaintiff's admissions or the advancement of the defendant's case,
> again through admissions. The defendant's examination of the plaintiff is
> called "cross-examination" or "cross-questioning". The scope of the cross-
> examination are the issues in the case. The defendant's representative, there-
> fore, may ask the plaintiff questions that relate to all matters at issue in the
> proceedings.

Abbreviate Cross Examination to CE. What motivated the choice of 'Cross'?

My guess: In a CE, the witness is not on the questioning lawyer's side, and so the lawyer must ask only questions that elicit a 'Yes/No' answer, to forestall any dodging by the witness. So the 'cross-' apparently suggests antipathy or enmity.

Comment: This is a question about English etymologies, better asked on the English SE.

Comment: We have a tag for terminology, and we're okay with history questions. Asking questions about historic terminology specific to law should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the 'cross-' apparently suggests antipathy or enmity.

No.

> In a CE, the witness is not on the questioning lawyer's side

Here is your answer.  To get to the other side of something, such as a street or a river, one must cross it.  It is cross-examination because the witness had been called by the other side.